# How to use apply, cat and print, without getting NULL

Tags: r, apply, cat

I am trying to use `cat()` as functions inside `apply()`. I can *almost* make R do what I want, but I'm getting some very confusing (to me) NULLS at the end of the return. Here is a silly example, to highlight what I'm getting.

```
val1 <- 1:10
val2 <- 25:34
values <- data.frame(val1, val2)
apply(values, 1, function(x) cat(x[1], x[2], fill=TRUE))
```

This "works" in that R accepts it and it runs, but I don't understand the results.

```
> apply(values, 1, function(x) cat(x[1], x[2], fill=TRUE))
1 25
2 26
3 27
4 28
5 29
6 30
7 31
8 32
9 33
10 34
NULL
```

But, I want to get:

```
> apply(values, 1, function(x) cat(x[1], x[2], fill=TRUE))
1 25
2 26
3 27
4 28
5 29
6 30
7 31
8 32
9 33
10 34
```

So, how do I remove that final NULL?

Comment: Have you looked at ddply from the plyr package?

Comment: No. I have never gotten the hang of plyr. Usually when I need to really reshape data, I stick the data frames into a database. Not that SQL is necessarily better, but I am often more comfortable beating against Postgres than I am R.

Comment: However, I should take the time to learn how to use plyr. I'm taking some time off next week for family stuff. Learning plyr would give me something to do in the evening.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The NULL is the R interpreter printing the value of the expression you typed in - the apply. You can either assign it somewhere:

```
junk = apply(values, 1, function(x) cat(x[1], x[2], fill=TRUE))
```

in which case it wont get printed, or wrap it in 'invisible':

```
invisible(apply(values, 1, function(x) cat(x[1], x[2], fill=TRUE)))
```

Note that its only when you run this interactively that each line is printed, if it's in a function you won't see it.

Comment: invisible() works. I also discovered that paste() works in the way I expected it to.

Comment: A note on this in case somebody else is as dense as I am: make sure the `invisible()` is for the whole `apply()` function, not just `cat()`! Took me a good 15 minutes to realize what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the `apply()` to loop through your content?

```
> print(values, row.names=FALSE)
 val1 val2
    1   25
    2   26
    3   27
    4   28
    5   29
    6   30
    7   31
    8   32
    9   33
   10   34
```

Comment: Do I need to use apply for my example? -- No. The example is just a simplified situation that highlights the problem I am having. I'm actually taking a bunch of numbers, from rows in a data.frame and providing something sensible for a report.

Comment: I fear you may be misunderstanding matters.  In an `apply()` you do not use `cat()` but rather slice, dice, aggregate and ... return a value.  Your failure to do so it at the root of the NULL display.

Comment: I always thought the use of apply was to use a function on an object without using a loop. In this case, I want to "aggregate" by concatenating a bunch of strings. paste() appears to do what I thought cat() would do.

Answer (score 0):

As Dirk pointed out this is not the way to print thing in R. Usually you would assign the result to a variable and then print it. No side effects, so to say.

Your problem stems from the cat functions, which prints to the terminal as a side effect, but returns NULL.

Try

```
a <- cat("blabla\n")  
a
```

If you really want to use apply for printing, there are two solutions. Wrap into invisible call

```
invisible(apply(values, 1, function(x) invisible(cat(x[1], x[2], fill=TRUE))))
```

or, just assign the result (NULL) to a temporary value

```
t <- apply(values, 1, function(x) invisible(cat(x[1], x[2], fill=TRUE)))
```

Comment: Too many languages. Too little time. cat() didn't work the way I expected it to. paste() does. I don't technically want to print them, I just want to take a bunch of stuff and concatenate it together into a string.

Comment: My initial post should not have included print(). That was misleading on my part. I misunderstood the use of cat() and find that paste() appears to work as I want.