# When I try to print using cat, it gives me back NULL in the very end

Tags: r, cat, side-effects

```
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)

model1 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())
model2 <- glm(counts ~ outcome, family = poisson())

print_params <- function(model){
  cat("\nAIC:", model$aic,
      "\nDeviance:", model$deviance)}

list_models <- list(model1,model2)
do.call("rbind", sapply(list_models, print_params, simplify = FALSE))
```

Which gives me:

```
AIC: 56.76132 
Deviance: 5.129141
AIC: 52.76132 
Deviance: 5.129141NULL
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: `print_params` returns `NULL`: what's the point of  `rbind` the results of it?

Answer (score 3):

`print_params` returns `NULL` (`cat` is a side effect), so if you look at the results of your `*apply`, you have the results of `cat`, then a list of two `NULL`s. The `do.call` then returns the results of your function, and then the results of `rbind`ing two `NULL`s, i.e. one `NULL`.

To just capture the side effects, simplifying your syntax slightly:

```
do.call("cat", lapply(list_models, print_params))
```

gives

```
AIC: 56.76132 
Deviance: 5.129141
AIC: 52.76132 
Deviance: 5.129141
```

Comment: Also, if you change the `cat` in `print_params` to `paste`, the results of the `lapply` will make more sense, because it will be a list of something. You'll still need to `cat` to print the `\n` characters, though, i.e. the `do.call` stays the same as my answer; what it's doing just makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The NULL is coming from the command line, evaluating what you typed in.  This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926106/how-to-use-apply-cat-and-print-without-getting-null) talks about it ([Spacedman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211116/spacedman)'s response).

They suggest that you wrap the function with invisible().  This works for me:

```
invisible(do.call("rbind", sapply(list_models, print_params, simplify = FALSE)))

AIC: 56.76132 
Deviance: 5.129141 

AIC: 52.76132 
Deviance: 5.129141
```